# one image pushing another from center

Tags: html, css

I have a logo that is pushing another image away from the center. I want topimage to be centered no matter how much margin I put on my logo.

html: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/index.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div id="topimage">
                <img src="images/church.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navmenu">
            <h1>Test text</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <div id="bottomleft">
                <h1>Welcome to Fictional Baptist Church</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="bottomright">
                <h1>Join us on Sunday nights for a special series of sermons</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample1/css/styles.css

```
#wrapper {z-index:5; width:900px; margin:auto;position: relative;}
#top {z-index:10; background-color:#80FFFF; margin:0;padding:0;position: relative;}
#logo {z-index:50; float:left; margin:0;padding:0;position: relative;}
#logo img {margin:50px 0 0 50px}
```

I'm sorry I can't figure out how to paste the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning with your logo div.

```
#logo { position:absolute; }
```

Comment: Np, also you should accept answer that works the most for you in each of the questions you made. :)

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to position absolute your logo instead of position absolute.

another way is to use 2 different layers like:

```
<div style='position:relative'>
<div id='layer1' style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'>
<img src=topimage.jpg' />
</div>
<div id='layer2' style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'>
<img src=logo.jpg' />
</div>
</div>
```